# как добавить большое количество запросов в контроллере PHP ( Laravel )

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Имеется код:

### ```js
  /**
     * Create a comment for tasks and leads
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);

        $source = $request->type == "task" ? Task::find($request->id) : Place::find($request->id);
        $comment = $source->addComment(['description' => $request->description, 'user_id' => auth()->user()->id]);
        event(new \App\Events\NewComment($comment));
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Comment successfully added!'); //Snippet in Master.blade.php
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Нас интересует строчка 13: 
$source = $request->type == "task" ? Task::find($request->id) : Place::find($request->id);

Я пытаюсь добавить больше запросов:
$source = $request->type == "task" ? Task::find($request->id) : Place::find($request->id) : Tel::find($request->id) : Adress::find($request->id) :;

Выдаёт конечно же ошибку....
FatalThrowableError
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

in CommentController.php line 27

Не могу понять в какую сторону копать, PHP или Laravel
Но понимаю что ошибка в (:)

Заранее благодарю о/

Comment: Вы бы хоть почитали о тернарном операторе.

Comment: if  $source = $request->type == "task"
        Task::find($request->id);
        elseif $source = $request->type == "lead"
          Place::find($request->id);
          elseif $source = $request->type == "client" 
            Tel::find($request->id);
            endif

Comment: ищу решение новой ошибки 
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function addComment() on string

in CommentController.php line 35

Comment: Штош, желаю успехов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решили проблему путем замены тернарного оператора на elseif

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

  if  ($source = $request->type == "task")
    Task::find($request->id);
    elseif ($source = $request->type == "tel")
      tel::find($request->id);
      elseif ($source = $request->type == "place")
        place::find($request->id);
```